# C# string passed to C++ CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Not seeing what I was looking for on S/O.   I have a C# app that needs to pass values to a C++ CLI application (managed code).   (I REALLY ONLY NEED TO FIGURE OUT STRING passing)

C# I have

```
double xCoordinate = 4820.85;
double yCoordinate = 9792.93;
string stringName = "My string stuff";
abc.Highlight(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, stringName);
```

In C++ / CLI I wish to receive the string (double seems just fine)

I read about the following

```
C++ --> std::wstring
or in C++  -->  extern "C" __declspec void GetString( char* buffer, int* bufferSize );
C# --> void GetString( StringBuilder buffer, ref int bufferSize );
```

Perhaps

```
System::String^
const char *
```

?  So it seems that I just wish to send string from C# to C++ / CLI  while it would seem simple enough, I'm not trained in  C++ and finding examples of Interop /marshalling does not seem so trivial.

Comment: I've retagged this as it doesn't seem applicable to `c++` or `managed-c++`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using C++/CLI, you can use `String` directly:

```
void Highlight(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate, String^ name)
{
    //...
```

Comment: So in C++ I would do   void Highlight(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate, String^ name)  and then in C# simply leave it as is?  thx

Comment: Why is String ambiguous?  what namespace in C++ CLI does the uppercase String belong to ?  (I recall looking it up and not seeing the answer)

Comment: Oh,   
using namespace System;  (  System::String^)